# display: none is flickering content that should be hidden when loading the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am building a toy website and I am getting some undesired behavior.

In my html file for my homepage, I have two distinct `<body>` tags sets.
The tags are as follows

```
<body class = "intro">...</body> 
<body class = "home">...</body>
```

The behavior that I am going for is that there will be a button within the "intro" class that when clicked, will hide the "intro" class and display the "home" class. The issue is, when I load the webpage, the "home" class displays for just a second and then gets covered up by the "intro" class. I do not want the "home" class being displayed at all until the button is clicked.

I do not have any javascript that I am using (at the moment at least, I was planning on adding that in later once I have all of my html and css set up).

I have tried linking to an external style sheet AND tried inline css that read

```
body{
     display: none;
 }
```

but even with the inline css, the content from the "home" class is displayed for about a second before the content disppears. Does anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double (or more) body tags is an invalid syntax. HTML should only have one body. Instead try using two divs

Comment: even when using two divs, the content still flickers for a second. and it ends up breaking my formatting when i use the div tags as opposed to the body tags

Comment: @ZJC all we can really do is guess at this point. You need to provide code in your question that will reproduce the problem. Start by turning the two body tags into two divs wrapped inside one body tag, put the classes on the divs, and see if that works. Fix your formatting to be relative to the divs.

Comment: the two div solution semi-worked. I found a kinda hacky way to adjust the formatting, but at least the hidden content isnt being displayed any further

Comment: @ZJC Glad to hear that. If the only problems you have left are formatting-related then it sounds like the issue you asked about is fixed, so I would probably go ahead and accept this answer.